# Replace brackets and everything within brackets with empty space (delete)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have to apologize I'm a complete newb... I'm trying to learn how to code using Google Apps Script. I would like the script to run and delete all brackets "[]" and everything within the brackets and replace with an empty space... I understand its best to do a loop but I'm just trying to get the basic function to execute.

My current code is...

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

body.replaceText("\\[1]", "");
body.replaceText("\\[2]", "");
body.replaceText("\\[3]", "");


}
```

But this only deletes the brackets and specified characters.. Is there a wildcard string?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `replaceText()` is a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), specifically a [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) regex. Try this:

```
  body.replaceText('\\[[\\s\\S]*?\\]', '');
```

Note that regex special characters need to be double escaped because the regex is passed as a text string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body.replaceText('\\[.*\\]','');
```